# ScriptMethod call from WebClient

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I'm trying to call a ScriptMethod (pagemethod) from server side (not from client side using jQuery) with WebClient, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is my very simple scriptmethod (as a page method)

```
    <Services.WebMethod()>
    <Script.Services.ScriptMethod()>
    Public Shared Function AddMemberToGroup() As String
        Return "a"
    End Function
```

And my caller is like the following:

```
Public Function JsonWebServiceCall(uri As String, data As String) As String
    Using wc As New WebClient
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        Return wc.UploadString(uri, data)
    End Using
End Function

Dim strReturned = JsonWebServiceCall("http://localhost/MemberList.aspx/AddMemberToGroup", "{}")
```

Whenever the code above executes, it returns "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." I also tried "" instead of "{}" but the result is the same.

Both the caller and the ScriptMethod reside on my server, inside the same web app.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my code is correct. The thing that's wrong is that I have a same name scriptmethod defined (different signature) in the same file. This doesn't work so I simply renamed my method and the code works now.